# Raspberry slow boot when a usb rfid reader is connected

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, boot, rfid, firmware

my raspberry works properly but when I connect a usb rfid reader the system takes 4 minutes to boot up. It only behaves this way when that device is connected. I originally thought it was a voltage issue but when I connect the raspberry to a usb hub and the reader to this hub it works properly. It works also when I connect other usb devices. I have updated also the firmware... someone can help me? Thank you.